# Alert box is not showing in codeigniter models

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

in the model alert is not working. if condition is working,the only problem with the alert box, its not showing the dialog box.Please help..

```
public function setJumlahPenumpang ($idJadwal,$idPemesanan,$jml,$booked,$selected){
    $data1 = $this->db->query('select p.jumlah_kursi, j.jumlah_penumpang, p.harga from tb_po p JOIN tb_jadwal j ON j.id_po = p.id_bus WHERE j.id_jadwal ='. $idJadwal);
    foreach ($data1->result_array() as $dataa1) {
        $tersedia = $dataa1['jumlah_kursi'] - $dataa1['jumlah_penumpang'];
        if($tersedia < $jml){
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.location = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>proses/cekKode1/<?php echo $idPemesanan ?>';
                alert("Tidak ada Bus Beroperasi");
                </script>
        <?php 
        }else{
            $data3 = $dataa1['harga'] * $jml;
            $this->db->query('update tb_pemesanan set harga = '.$data3.' where id_pemesanan = '.$idPemesanan);
            $data = $this->db->query('select jumlah_penumpang from tb_jadwal where id_jadwal ='. $idJadwal);
            $this->db->query("update tb_jadwal set booked = '".$booked."' where id_jadwal = ".$idJadwal);
            $this->db->query("update tb_pemesanan set kursi = '".$selected."' where id_pemesanan = ".$idPemesanan);
            foreach ($data->result_array() as $dataa) {
                $data2 = $dataa['jumlah_penumpang'] + $jml;
                $this->db->query('update tb_jadwal set jumlah_penumpang = '.$data2.' where id_jadwal = '.$idJadwal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try using alert before document.location , Also for cross-browser safety, use window.location instead. Where is this function called and used ? Javascript don't work on server side

Answer (score 0):

Try Echo Before Script Tag I hope So it 'll work....

```
if($package_id == NULL) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
             window.location.href = "'.base_url().'"
               </script>';
               return;
           die();
     }
```